# JHipster 504 Gateway Timeout when trying to call a microservice

Tags: jhipster

[Registry Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqFTF.png)

One instance of my microservice is down and when I try to make a rest call to that microservice it won't work even though alot of other instances are up and running.

I don't quite understand and the error logs don't help much either. Do I need to manually switch to another instance? I thought its the job of the registry to take care of these things?

I haven't changed anything in the service class:

```
public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'productms/api/products';

find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

regards

Comment: How do you make your REST call?

Comment: I use the service class from the API Gateway.

Comment: You mean an angular service? Which URL does it use ? Please edit your question with details if you want help.

Comment: I edited the question. Any other information you need in order to assist me? I really haven't changed much and absolutely nothing in any service class. It works in the meantime but only because I restarted everything. Still interesting to know why this happened and if it could happen again.

Comment: Well there are many reasons why you would get a tiemout depending on how long your service takes to respond and how you configured various timeout properties in gateway configuration. There could be also a timeout only on first request to proxified service due to lazy init, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1783